# How do i get the 304 status code with $http.get?

Tags: angularjs

How do i get the 304 status code with $http.get ?

```
$http.get('menu.json').success(function(data, status, headers){
$scope.menu = data;
console.log(status); ## shows 200 but its actually 304 ##
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. XMLHttpRequest handles `3xx` responses transparently, so the data you get is that of the original (cached) response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, clear answer, but do u also know an easy way so i still get my 304 from somewhere with a built in Angular function? Or am i approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: The browser doesn't expose the information to JavaScript at all. You cannot get that information. (You *might* be able to figure out something equivalent by examining the Last-Modified header).